# Bug in my lazyload plugin for mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to implement a plug-in serial download pictures in MooTools. Let's say there are pictures with the img tag inside a div with the class imageswrapper. Need to consistently download each image after it loads the next and so on until all the images are not loaded.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
// get all images in div with class 'imageswrapper'
var imagesArray = $$('.imageswrapper img');
var tempProperty = '';
// hide them and set them to the attribute 'data-src' to cancel the background download
for (var i=0; i<imagesArray.length; i++) {
    tempProperty = imagesArray[i].getProperty('src');
    imagesArray[i].removeProperty('src');
    imagesArray[i].setProperty('data-src', tempProperty);
}

tempProperty = '';
var iterator = 0;

// select the block in which we will inject Pictures
var injDiv = $$('div.imageswrapper');

// recursive function that executes itself after a new image is loaded
function imgBomber() {
    // exit conditions of the recursion
    if (iterator > (imagesArray.length-1)) {
        return false; 
    }
    tempProperty = imagesArray[iterator].getProperty('data-src');
    imagesArray[iterator].removeProperty('data-src');
    imagesArray[iterator].setProperty('src', tempProperty);
    imagesArray[iterator].addEvent('load', function() {
        imagesArray[iterator].inject(injDiv);
        iterator++;
        imgBomber();
    });

} ;
imgBomber();
});
```

Comment: please don't forget to click to accept this answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues I can see here. You have not actually said what the issue is so... this is more of a code review / ideas for you until you post the actual problems with it (or a jsfiddle with it)

- you run this code in `domready` where the browser may have already initiated the download of the images based upon the src property. you will be better off sending `data-src` from server directly before you even start
- **Probably biggest problem** is: `var injDiv = $$('div.imageswrapper');` will return a COLLECTION  - so `[<div.imageswrapper></div>, ..]` - which cannot take an `inject` since the target can be multiple dom nodes. use `var injDiv = document.getElement('div.imageswrapper');` instead.
- there are issues with the `load` events and the `.addEvent('load')` for cross-browser. they need to be cleaned up after execution as in IE < 9, it will fire `load` every time an animated gif loops, for example. also, you don't have `onerror` and `onabort` handlers, which means your loader will stop at a 404 or any other unexpected response.
- you should not use `data-src` to store the data, it's slow. MooTools has Element storage - use `el.store('src', oldSource)` and `el.retrieve('src')` and `el.eliminate('src')`. much faster.
- you expose the iterator to the upper scope.
- use mootools api - use `.set()` and `.get()` and not `.getProperty()` and `.setProperty()`
- `for (var i)` iterators are unsafe to use for async operations. control flow of the app will continue to run and different operations may reference the wrong iterator index. looking at your code, this shouldn't be the case but you should use the mootools `.each(fn(item, index), scope)` from `Elements` / `Array` method.

Anyway, your problem has already been solved on several layers.

Eg, I wrote [pre-loader](https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/pre-loader) - a framework agnostic image loader plugin that can download an array of images either in *parallel* or *pipelined* (like you are trying to) with `onProgress` etc events - see http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/mFQm6/ - see the screenshots at the bottom of the readme.md:

[image: pipeline waterfall]

[image: parallel waterfall]

MooTools solves this also (without the wait on previous image) via Asset.js - http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets#Asset:Asset-image and Asset.images for multiple. see the source for inspiration - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Utilities/Assets.js

Here's an example doing this via my pre-loader class: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/JhpsH/

```
(function(){
    var imagesToLoad = [],
        imgDiv = document.getElement('div.injecthere');

    $$('.imageswrapper img').each(function(el){
        imagesToLoad.push(el.get('src'));
        el.erase('src');
    });

    new preLoader(imagesToLoad, {
        pipeline: true, // sequential loading like yours
        onProgress: function(img, imageEl, index){
            imgDiv.adopt(imageEl);
        }
    });

}());
```